# Python - calculate JAMCRC from string without converting it to bytes

Tags: python, string, character-encoding, byte, crc32

I'm learning Python 3 and my question is: it possible to calculate JAMCRC from a string without converting the string to bytes (without encoding it)? I'm currently using this code:

```
import zlib

result = int('0b'+'1'*32,2) - zlib.crc32('ł'.encode('cp852'))
print(result)
```

but `zlib` requires a byte-like object as a parameter. I'm comparing the JAMCRC results with a Windows third-party program, and string encoding is causing different results. The results are equal if a use standard ASCII characters, but results are different when I use Polish letters. I want my script to always calculate JAMCRC result equal to this Windows program. For example, when I set the encoding to `8859` the results for letter `ó` from both programs (my script and third-party Windows program) are equal; but I cannot do it with letter `ł` because `ł` is not supported by `8859` encoding; I can change encoding to `cp852` but the CRC result is different from the other program. The results was always equal when I used only standard ASCII characters and `utf-8` encoding and results started to be different when I started to use Polish characters. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Later I've learned that the answer is: No - CRC works on bytes. Besides, different results were caused by different encoding.